# Invalid selectOptions found. Use SelectOption type in Apex (why?)

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

I was trying to add a dropdown menu inside VF page (where I already have other pageBlockTables).
I only need to retrieve one field (c.sfprn) from an existing SOQL query where it is already used for other pageBlockTables.

Here is part of my VF page where I am trying to add a dropdown menu:

```
    <!-- DropDown Menu starts -->
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RowList}" var="c">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">All Surveys</apex:facet>
                <span>All Surveys: </span>
            <apex:selectList id="AllSurvey" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="http://www.test.com?sfprn={!c.sfprn}&id=1>Test1</apex:selectOptions>
            <apex:selectOptions value="http://www.test.com?sfprn={!c.sfprn}&id=2>Test1</apex:selectOptions>
            </apex:selectList> 
            </apex:column>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
         <!-- DropDown Menu ends -->
```

Here is portion of Apex code:

```
public PageReference searchPatients(){

    RowList = new List<TableRow2>();
    TableRow2 tr;

    for(Patient__c con : [SELECT sfprn__c, 
                                mrn__c,
                                LName__c, 
                                FName__c,
                                (select SurveySelection__c.SurveySelection__c from SurveySelections__r) 
                                FROM Patient__c
                                where mrn__c =:mrn 
                                or LName__c =:lname LIMIT 1                                
                                ]){

        tr = new TableRow2();
        tr.sfprn = con.sfprn__c;
        tr.mrn = con.mrn__c;
        tr.lname = con.LName__c;
        tr.fname = con.FName__c;
        tr.SurveySelection = con.SurveySelections__r.isEmpty() ? null : con.SurveySelections__r[0].SurveySelection__c;

        RowList.add(tr);
        }
     return null;   
}
```

I am curious whether I need to add a new method or I could just call the value="{!RowList}" to bring one field (c.sfprn).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a closing " for them

Comment: Opps. I added (along with bottom correction), but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apex:selectOptions` is for adding a list of `SelectOption` objects from Apex.  If you want to define the options in visualforce, use `apex:selectOption`:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RowList}" var="c">
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">All Surveys</apex:facet>
        <span>All Surveys: </span>
        <apex:selectList id="AllSurvey" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="http://www.test.com?sfprn={!c.sfprn}&id=1" itemLabel="Test1"></apex:selectOption>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="http://www.test.com?sfprn={!c.sfprn}&id=2" itemLabel="Test1"></apex:selectOption> 
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: I changed to <apex:selectOption> , but still getting "Invalid selectOptions found. Use SelectOption type in Apex." error.

Comment: @KingJava `value` may not actually be supported, try `itemValue`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi IllusiveBrian. Thanks. The drop down is working, but it does not go to URL.

Comment: @KingJava If you need it to go to the URL, you would need to use javascript or `apex:actionSupport`.  If you need help with that, you should post another question.

Comment: I posted it. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175675/how-to-apply-apexactionsupport-to-trigger-http-action  Thanks!