# How to apply Apex:ActionSupport to trigger HTTP action

Tags: apex, visualforce, ajax

I am trying to use **apex:actionSupport** to trigger an URL (along with calling a value , **c.sfprn** , from {!RowList}.

Currently, dropdown menu works, but when an user clicks the dropdown, nothing triggers.

Here is my code.
How do I go about doing it?

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RowList}" var="c">
    <apex:column >
         <apex:facet name="header">All Surveys</apex:facet>
            <span>All Surveys: </span>
                <apex:selectList id="AllSurvey" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="http://www.test.com?sfprn={!c.sfprn}&id=1" itemLabel="Test1"></apex:selectOption>                     
                </apex:selectList>
     </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to open the selected URL on a new window.

Then no need to use actionSupport. Javascript `window.open()` at `onchange` event will serve your purpose.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RowList}" var="c">
    <apex:column >
         <apex:facet name="header">All Surveys</apex:facet>
            <span>All Surveys: </span>
                <apex:selectList id="AllSurvey" size="1" onchange="javascript:window.open(this.value)">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="http://www.test.com?sfprn={!c.sfprn}&id=1" itemLabel="Test1"></apex:selectOption>                     
                </apex:selectList>
     </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```